# Writing Order of Elements to Database in jQuery UI Sortable (BackboneJS, Rails)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was hoping to get some feedback before I start implementing a way to write the "order" of my client-side HTML elements to the server by using jQuery's Sortable UI.

I have:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable-lists" ).sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    $( "#sortable-lists" ).disableSelection();
  });
</script>
```

I also have the `div`'s that I'd like to sort:

```
<div id="sortable-lists">
    <div id="id_1">Model here with server ID 1</div>
    <div id="id_2">Model here with server ID 2</div>
    <div id="id_3">Model here with server ID 3</div>
</div>
```

The `div` id's basically represent the model's IDs as they are in the database. My models also have an "**order**" property/column that allows them to become sorted using BackboneJS's `comparator` method. My idea is to
(1) Send the data to Rails using an AJAX request
(2) Rails then iterates through the data array, finding the model with the corresponding ID
(3) The model's **order** property is then updated in accordance with the index in the array

I was wondering how other people would implement this? What better ways are there to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Do it clientwise, no need to do it on the backend. Simply keep an array with the ordered list, updating it whenever you reorder the models. Only reason I can think of why you should do it server side is if you have a lot of data and you're concerned with performance. But it seems to me that number of models isn't really that big here.

Comment: @SamirAlajmovic, then what happens if you push "refresh"?

Comment: Then you just do, $('#sortable-lists').append( the saved and ordered list elements ); Basically, you recreate the li DOM elements on load.